# Пошаговая форма заказа на vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form

Пытаюсь сделать форму на сайте. но мне надо реализовать это на vue и сделать форму пошаговой (заполнили поля, нажали на кнопку продолжить и появилось следующее окно, в котором уже следующие поля ввода). и вот уже на втором окне будет кнопка: "оформить". vue знаю еще не очень хорошо. поэтому  подскажите куда мыслить)

Comment: двигайтесь в напревлении написания какого-либо кода. А дальше логика подскажет, что делать

Comment: Попробуйте сами расписать на листочке как и куда двигаться, с чего начинать. Лучше посидеть самому, чем сразу узнать готовый ответ.

Comment: Какие примеры есть для наглядности?

Answer (score -1):

В родительском компоненте задай state где будет храниться значение формы и состояние шага заказа. Создай 2 дочерних компонента и в них пиши формы и при изменений формы или нажатие на события (Двигаться дальше) кидай в родительский компонент а там уже поставь условия на отображение двух дочерних компонентов.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь хоть буду иметь представление. отпишусь когда получится))